# Converting a stored procedure LINQ result list to a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures, datatable

I am modifying some working code to convert some code to using LINQ calls to a stored procedure.  It makes the C# look neater for the most part.

This current code invokes the stored procedure to create a data table which is then sent to openxml to create an excel spreadsheet for download.  This approach works.

I want to modify this to invoke the SP from LINQ.
I am invoking a stored procedure from LINQ to get a list. However, the openxml requires a DataTable.

The code I have looks something like this:

```
using (TEMPDataContext dbc = new TEMPDataContext(connectionString))
{
    GetTestPlanquestionnaireResult tq  = (GetTestPlanquestionnaireResult) dbc.GetTestPlanquestionnaire(tbStartDate.Text, tbEndDate.Text);       

    DataTable tbl = tq.ConvertToDataTable();        

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(ms))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Results");


        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);

        ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, tbl.Columns.Count].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, tbl.Columns.Count].AutoFitColumns();

        pck.Save();
    }
    byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();

    Context.Response.ClearContent();
    Context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"downloadfilename.xlsx\"");  
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Context.Response.End();
}
```

My issue is with that line in the code which invokes the method that does not yet exist; namely `DataTable tbl = tq.ConvertToDataTable();`

I haven't written any code for `ConvertToDataTable()` as it's inconceivable to me that something doesn't already exist to do this.  If that's the level of irritation, then I'm probably going to just leave the stuff as as-is and not worry about conversion to LINQ.  Is there a way to do this that is simple and easy to read?

Comment: Not all Lists are collections of flat objects so it would not make sense to have a framework-provided List-to-datatable feature. I personally would not bother using EF to call stored procedures, couple that with your need for a DataTable and I'd recommend just keeping it as is.

Comment: Very good. That sounds like the right answer.

Comment: You can convert simple objects into datatable with reflection easily, but I see no advantage here. SqlDataAdapter can read the result into datatable completely on its own.

Comment: This has nothing to do with openXML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are still interested, this is from my LINQPad extensions file:

```
public static DataTable AsDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rows) {
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var infos = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var info in infos)
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType));

    foreach (var r in rows) {
        var nr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < infos.Length; ++i) {
            nr[i] = infos[i].GetValue(r);
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(nr);
    }
    return dt;
}

public static EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> AsDataRows<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rows) => rows.AsDataTable().AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Why not have `AsDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rows)`? Then you can substitute the ugly `rows.First().GetType()` with `typeof(T)`.